# How to apply Wordpress header/footer in Prestashop

Tags: wordpress, prestashop, wordpress-ecommerce

I have created a Wordpress site and I want to implement Prestashop in my website. I don't want to use plugins. I placed Prestashop folder inside the directory of my Wordpress site and installed it. Now, my problem is how to apply the header of my Wordpress site in Prestashop. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make backups.
You should copy CSS and some HTML from header.php (WP) but whithout any wordpress-shortcodes, simple HTML and paste/overite in header.tpl in your Prestashop theme. And do similar actions whith footer.php in footer.tpl

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. The page displays white only. Nothing text or anything. Just pure white.

Comment: Prestashop and Wordpress both have different structure, you cant do this directly as you suggested.